# Redirecting form to unique URL in Gatsby?

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I am new to Gatsby and I am trying to create a form that goes to a unique URL based on Selection. It needs to go to a third party site for checkout.

The code below works fine on a standard HTML page, but not at all when added to Gatsby.

The errors are;
TypeError: Cannot set property 'onsubmit' of null

```
 }
  18 |   , myForm = document.getElementById('order-form');
> 19 | myForm.onsubmit = e => {
  20 |   e.preventDefault()
  21 |   if (myForm.option.value)
  22 |     document.location = direction[myForm.option.value]
```

```
<form action="" id="order-form">
  <label> Quantity 1  <input type="radio" name="option" value="Option1" > </label>
  <label> Quantity 2 <input type="radio" name="option" value="Option2" > </label>
  <label>Quantity 3 <input type="radio" name="option" value="Option3" > </label>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

```
const 
  direction = 
    {
    Option1: 'https://www.example.com/cart/31852303417409:1',
    Option2: 'https://www.example.com/cart/31852303417409:2',
    Option3: 'https://www.example.com/cart/31852303417409:3',
    }
, myForm = document.getElementById('order-form')
  ;
myForm.onsubmit=e=>
  {
  e.preventDefault()
  if (myForm.option.value) 
     document.location = direction[ myForm.option.value  ]
  }
```

I appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Gatsby, so in React too, you are creating a virtual DOM instead of attacking the real one, so, it can be considered bad practice to refer directly to the DOM objects such as `document` to point to any element. In addition, that's why React is so fast because pointing the real DOM has a huge performance effect. You can use [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) hook that recreates the same behavior in the virtual DOM.

Your code should be adapted to:

```
const orderForm=useRef(null); 

const yourSubmitFunction=e=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if(orderForm.current.option.value){
       document.location = direction[myForm.option.value]
    }
}

return <form action="" id="order-form" onSubmit={yourSubmitFunction} ref="orderForm">
      <label> Quantity 1  <input type="radio" name="option" value="Option1" > </label>
      <label> Quantity 2 <input type="radio" name="option" value="Option2" > </label>
      <label>Quantity 3 <input type="radio" name="option" value="Option3" > </label>
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
```

Let's dive step by step.

It's a good practice to initialize a reference to `null` to avoid cached values when rehydrating the component.

`event` (`e`) it's a default parameter so you can't omit them because a submit function always has it.

As I said, `document.getElementById` it's a pointer to the real DOM, but with references, `orderForm.current` has exactly the same object data as `document.getElementById` so you can keep that condition with a little refactoring.

Finally, I don't know your use-case but, you may want to use a `window.location` if the navigation is external or use a [`navigate`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/gatsby-link/#how-to-use-the-navigate-helper-function) if you are redirecting the user to any internal page.